# transfer some amount from one column to another of same table in single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
ID | Amount
-------------
1  | 500
2  | 800
3  | 200
```

How can I transfer 300 from second row to first row using their Id, I can do it by Stored Procedure, is there any way to perform this in single query

Comment: You can do it with inner query

Comment: Tell us what you have tried..

Comment: You can use update with case and when

Comment: To be more explicit you want to increase the value of row 1 by 300 and decrease the value if row 2 by 300?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I want to transfer 300 from id 2 to id 1. By a single query

Comment: @parthivrshah I have a solution of this by using Stored Procedure, I am expecting single query solution(If possible) by experienced developer on this amazing platform.

Comment: @parthivrshah can i add condition, amount must not exceed than available amount in same query

Comment: What is the available amount?

Comment: @parthivrshah assume any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE table_users
    SET amount = (case when id = 1 then amount+300
                         when id = 2 then amount-300
                    end)
    WHERE id in (1,2);
```

Comment: This is the way to do in the single query. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

MySql evaluates Boolean expressions as 1 or 0, so this will work:

```
update tablename
set amount = amount + (id = 1) * 300 - (id = 2) * 300
where id in (1, 2);
```

Or:

```
update tablename
set amount = amount + ((id = 1) - (id = 2)) * 300
where id in (1, 2);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vjW5GuHkVL6H1iucHe65Hk/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Amount |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 800    |
| 2   | 500    |
| 3   | 200    |
```

Comment: @Nick Why? Doesn't `(id = 1) - (id = 2)` make sense?

Comment: It only makes sense if you know that MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context. If you came across this code without knowing that and without the explanation in your answer it could be hard to understand. The other solution is a lot easier to read and understand, but I love this one's minimalism. Hence I upvoted both.

Comment: amazing answer, It took me 2 minute to understand it, if you don't mind can you let us know which one is better yours or the another answer and why.

Comment: @PramodYadav both are using conditional assignment. You have to consider efficiency, maintainability and readability. Personally this is one of Mysql features that I like.